# Unavailable preferred APN for secondary users on multi-user environment

Tags: android, android-multiple-users

Currently on my code I'm doing the following to obtain the preferred APN on a device:

```
public static final Uri PREFERAPN_URI = Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/preferapn");
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(PREFERAPN_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

And this works fine on most of the devices I've used.

But in some testing I've made with a tablet with multiple users I've found out that the code mentioned above, only works on the main user returning successfully the preferred APN. For the other,2 users it was not possible to get the preferred APN.

Can some one help me?

Thank you.